# Spring MVC & JSP: How to pass a parameter from the controller to JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have 2 JSP pages, in the first I have input text forms, I want to display the values inserted  in another JSP page. (using Spring MVC).

Comment: show what you tried already.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Put your variable that you want to transfer to the next page in a hidden field (put the fields in the same form which take you to next page. then get your parameter by JSTL. this is an example :

```
<form:form action="/nextPage" method="POST" commandName="cmd">

         <input type="hidden" value="Myname" name="nom" />
         <input type="hidden" value="myPPR" name="ppr" />

</form:form>
```

the controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/nextPage",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String FicheService(@ModelAttribute CMDBean cmd,BindingResult result,@RequestParam("nom") String nom, @RequestParam("ppr") Integer ppr,ModelMap model){
    model.addAttribute("ppr", ppr);
    model.addAttribute("nom", nom);


}
```

then get them in the second page like that :

```
<c:out value="${ppr}" />
<c:out value="${nom}  />
```