# Appending url params to existing with Spring tags

Tags: spring, jsp, url, tags

How to append more params to existing url?

I have this url:

```
http://localhost:8080/start/users?page=1
```

And i want to stick more params in JSP view like:

```
http://localhost:8080/start/users?page=1&sort=name&order=asc
```

How to do it by Spring tags. Or maybe there is another way to do it?
Can someone help?

Comment: May bee this link will give you some idea . I found this related to your problem please have a look .
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16927809/spring-mvc-jsp-how-to-pass-a-parameter-from-the-controller-to-jsp

Comment: @AmitGuleria Solution is to add param to model in controller?I'm right?